# Android RotateDrawable: Doesn't correctly work for Vector Drawables

Tags: android, svg, vector, rotation, android-drawable

Was observed a WONDERFUL issue when using a **Vector Drawable** in a `RotateDrawble`, two times per each *full cycle (0° to 360° / `level: 0 → 10000`)*! First about **90°  (`level: 2500`)** and another about **270° (`level: 7500`)**. See below test:

---

My `RotateDrawable` (File Name: `rotatable_info.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp" >
</rotate>
```

My layout design:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView style="@style/style" android:id="@+id/ImageView00" />
    <ImageView style="@style/style" android:id="@+id/ImageView01" />
    <ImageView style="@style/style" android:id="@+id/ImageView02" />
    ...
    <ImageView style="@style/style" android:id="@+id/ImageView19" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The referenced style:

```
<style name="style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/rotatable_info</item>
</style>
```

My code:

```
int n = -550;
((RotateDrawable) this.<ImageView>findViewById(R.id.ImageView00).getDrawable()).mutate().setLevel(n+=550);
((RotateDrawable) this.<ImageView>findViewById(R.id.ImageView01).getDrawable()).mutate().setLevel(n+=550);
...
((RotateDrawable) this.<ImageView>findViewById(R.id.ImageView18).getDrawable()).mutate().setLevel(n+=550);
((RotateDrawable) this.<ImageView>findViewById(R.id.ImageView19).getDrawable()).mutate().setLevel(n+=550);
```

(`.mutate()` is needed for acting rotation independently for each `ImageView`. It has not an effect on the main issue.)

My result (!?!?):

[image: Wonderful RotateDrawable for Vectors]

---

`ic_info_black_24dp.xml`: (Generated by Vector Asset Studio in Android Studio ... I also tested some other SVGs. **There is no problem for raster drawables**.)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM13,17h-2v-6h2v6zM13,9h-2L11,7h2v2z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: @pskink; Do you mean using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` and `app:srcCompat`instead of `ImageView` and `android:src`? These changes made no difference.

Comment: @pskink; From [official page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat): _In order to refer to VectorDrawableCompat inside a XML file, you can use app:srcCompat attribute in AppCompat library's ImageButton or ImageView._  ///  I tested on Android 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug. `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` solved the problem.

See *"Vector drawables backward compatibility solution" section* of below page for details:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources